# Migrating from classic nexus3 installation to a containerized installation with Docker

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I'm currently trying to migrate from a classic Nexus Repo 3.18.1 installation (nexus ran from the binary with `./nexus start`) to a containerized version with Docker (3.30.1).

Looking at the [Moving nexus article](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010352014-Moving-a-Nexus-Repo-3-Installation-to-a-New-Location) the process seems straightforward, but focuses on two directories I will need to move:

- the application directory
- the data directory
- (the blob storage, but in my case it's under the data directory, so it doesn't matter)

The problem I'm facing is that in the [official docker documentation for sonatype/nexus3](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3) only one volume is specified, and it's the one relative to the data directory.

How am I supposed to move the application directory into the container? From what I've seen by ssh'ing into a clean new sonatype/nexus3 container I can see that the application directory is located in `/opt/sonatype/nexus`, should I just use another volume to mount the existing files into that directory? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Try the volume mount on both the directory and see if it works for you. There is nothing wrong in doing that. The `VOLUME` declared is a metadata and doesn't stop from other volume sharing

Comment: Moving the application directory is totally irrelevant in your situation: the application is inside your image, overriding this with an older one is totally non-sense. My 2 cent: don't "migrate". [Backup your installation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/backup-and-restore/prepare-a-backup). Create your mount docker volume, then copy the blobstore there, and follow the doc to [push your metadata backups](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/backup-and-restore/restore-exported-databases). Start the container, wait for db to rebuild and upgrade, done.